# Are there any more powerful XML parsers than the one built into jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse XML feeds from YouTube using jQuery (by doing `$(xml).find(...)`), but jQuery is having really hard time with those. YouTube feeds are real mess - they have bunch of namespace tags, escaped html tags with inline styles and what not.

Are there any more powerful javascript XML parsers out there (preferably jQuery-compatible) that can chew such mess?

Comment: Is the youtube JSON API not an option?

Comment: @Nick damn I spent two days pulling hair off my head, while all I needed was to add `&alt=json` to url haha. Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it, thanks :)

Comment: For the record, there's no XML parser built into jQuery. It just uses the browser's native abilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of XML parsing pain, check out the JSON response format the API offers.

You can check out the [YouTube JSON API Documentation here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html).

Answer (score 1):

YouTube also supports JSON which may be easier to work with from jQuery.  You can find a starter at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json.html.

Answer (score 0):

http://simplepie.org/ is a fast processor for PHP.

Comment: Did you look into jFeed? http://www.hovinne.com/blog/index.php/2007/07/15/132-jfeed-jquery-rss-atom-feed-parser-plugin